# Grouping and displaying MySQL results by categories using multidimensional array

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following script which creates a multidimensional array from a MySQL query and prints the results according to categories like:

**CSF (infection)**
Glucose
Protein (Spot Urine)

**Blood gases**
Bicarbonate (Fluid)
pH (Fluid)
Oxygen partial pressure (tension)(pO2)

**Creatinine clearance**
Creatinine (Fluid)
Creatinine (24 hour Urine)

```
$test_groups = array();

$query = "SELECT * FROM 
lab_test, 
model_lab_test_lookup, 
lab_test_group 
WHERE 
lab_test.lab_test_pk = model_lab_test_lookup.lab_test_fk
 AND 
model_lab_test_lookup.lab_test_group_fk = lab_test_group.lab_test_group_pk
 AND 
model_lab_test_lookup.pathway_fk = '$pathway' 
GROUP BY lab_test.lab_test_pk";

$result = mysql_query($query, $connection) or die(mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

$test_groups[$row['group_name']][] = $row['lab_test'];

}

foreach($test_groups as $group_name => $tests){
        echo '<strong>' . $group_name . '</strong><br />';
        foreach($tests as $test){
               echo $test . '<br />';
        }
        echo '<p>';
    }
```

Now I want to add columns in addition to `$row['lab_test']` (the test name), e.g `$row['lab_test_pk']` and `$row['interval']` and be able to access those columns as happens in the `foreach` loops.

Like

```
$test_groups[$row['group_name']] = array(
                    'test_pk' => $row['lab_test_pk'],
                    'test_name' => $row['lab_test'],
                    'interval'  => $row['interval']
                    );
```

What is the right way of doing this and then accessing the added columns in the last foreach loop?

Comment: If you have used these columns in query then fine;                     $test_groups[$row['group_name']][] = 
$row['lab_test'],"." 
$row['lab_test_pk'],  "."
$row['interval'];

Comment: There appears to be an error in there somewhere...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$row['lab_test_pk'].','.$row['lab_test'].','.$row['interval'];
```

Try the above line and use . to append.

Comment: Yes, that appends the other columns OK, but how would I access those columns independantly in the last foreach loop, e.g. $test['lab_test'] doesn't work...nor does $test[1]

Answer (score 1):

Using part solution provided by @N.M.N I have the following working:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

    $test_groups[$row['group_name']][] = $row['lab_test_pk'].','.$row['lab_test'].','.$row['interval'];

  }

  foreach($test_groups as $group_name => $tests){
    echo '<strong>' . $group_name . '</strong><br />';
    foreach($tests as $test){
        list($test_pk, $test_name, $test_interval) = explode(',', $test);
        echo $test_pk . '<br />';
        echo $test_name . '<br />';
        echo $test_interval . '<br />';
    }
    echo '<p>';
}
```